# Comparison of sizes of a function and its integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous, positive and increasing for $x \geq 1$, and $g(2x)\leq Cg(x)$ for some number $C>0$ and all $x$. Suppose also that $f(x)=o(\int_1^x f(t)\,dt)$ for $x \rightarrow +\infty$, my question is how to show that $f(x)g(x)=o(\int_1^x f(t)g(t)\,dt)$ for $x \rightarrow +\infty$.

Any help would be appreciated.